# Nesting std::containers of movable objects

Tags: c++, containers, movable

I have a class `NoCopy` that is **movable**, but **not copiable**.

I need to make a **vector of 3 queues of `NoCopy`**. I can create an empty one, but there is no way to add any element.

I can make a `std::vector<NoCopy>` or `std::queue<NoCopy>` and populate them. But not for `std::vector<std::queue<NoCopy>>`.

MWE:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class NoCopy{
public:
    NoCopy() = default;
    NoCopy& operator = (const NoCopy&) = delete;
    NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;

    NoCopy(NoCopy&&) = default;
    NoCopy& operator = (NoCopy&&) = default;

};
using QNC = std::queue<NoCopy>;

int main(void) {
    QNC q;
    q.push(std::move(NoCopy()));

    std::vector<NoCopy> ncvec;
    ncvec.emplace_back();

    std::cout << "Queue size " << q.size() << ", vector size: " << ncvec.size() << std::endl;

    std::vector<QNC> qvec;
    //????

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could start with a vector of three empty queues and then populate those or swap them with an existing queue: `std::vector<QNC> qvec(3); qvec[0].swap(q); qvec[1].push(NoCopy());`

Comment: The problem seems to be that vector requires noexcept move semantics, and std::queue does not propagate its own move semantics' noexcept-ness from the underlying value

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [Ditto.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04dc855fe6479bd2)  Is [this workaround](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b064256725d3b4ea) legal?

Comment: You can use ncvec.emplace_back(q), emplace_back() uses move semantics.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It actually does propagate that, but that’s not good enough; I wrote an answer.

Comment: @jrok: No, you mustn’t specialize type traits (except `std::common_type`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default,`std::queue` is based on `std::deque`, which is not guaranteed to be **nothrow-movable**.  Neither is the other suitable standard container, `std::list`; these rules allow implementations that always allocate at least one node/block.  `std::vector` uses copies to reallocate when moving might throw (so as to guarantee exception safety) unless the type is not copyable at all, and those two containers also do not propagate **non-copyability** from their element type but just fail if you try.  The last could be said to be a defect in the standard, since expectations for such propagation keep going up, but fixing it is incompatible with support for *incomplete* types:

```
struct Node {
  std::vector<Node> children;
  // …
};
```

Note that both libstdc++ and libc++ **do** make those two containers nothrow-movable (as of version 9 in each case), which is a permitted extension, but MSVC’s STL does not.

You can still use `std::vector<QNC> v(3);`; the constructor “knows” that **re**allocation is never necessary.  Or you can provide a **wrapper** (*e.g.*, a class derived from `std::queue`) that is non-copyable or is nothrow-movable; the former will waive the exception safety of `std::vector`, while the latter will call `std::terminate` if moving the underlying container *does* throw.

Comment: Hats down for a rigorous analysis, thank you very much! Eventually, `std::vector<QNC> v(3);` worked for me, I hope that i will never have to resize the vector, else i will have to wrap it.
One reason why I haven't figured this out that is worth mentioning: I had `std::vector<QNC> qvec` as a member variable of another class, and attempted to default initialize it in the header file. This kind of initialization only allows `{x};`or `=x;` initialization, and I tend to avoid using braces `std::vector<QNC> qvec {3};` if result is call to a non initializer-list call.

Comment: @OndřejNavrátil: Using list-initialization carefully makes sense.  It can be a bit verbose, but you can always write `T mem=T(3);` in a class; since C++17, that doesn’t even require movability.